# I want install Windows Xp

Tags: windows

i have Ubuntu 13.10 , but now i want Windows Xp.

1.I insert cd press F12 (my computer dell n5050) use CD-DRIVE and press enter. When come boot CD I press enter and see black screen.

So how install Windows Xp?

Thank you for your Advice

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter your BIOS and set as first boot CD-ROM.
Beware if you install Windows XP you will not be able to load Ubuntu, because Grub2 will be replaced by NTLDR.